# What's the size of a word in the EOS virtual machine?

Tags: architecture

What does the low level architecture look like? I'm wondering about word sizes specifically.

Answer (score 7):

It is all based upon Web Assembly specification which I believe is 32 bit at this time.

https://github.com/sunfishcode/wasm-reference-manual/blob/master/WebAssembly.md

Comment: Oh that's interesting. Ethereum uses 256-bit words so I thought EOS might follow something similar.